# How to add play-pause functionality to a dynamic element of a webpage

Tags: javascript, video, dynamic, django-templates

I have officially exhausted my thought capabilities of this one (probably because I'm a noob to javascript) but I have a webpage where all of the elements are dynamically created from a database on that site. I have the ability for people to post videos and I want to create my own player so that I can add the functionality I want to the page. Thing is that because the elements are dynamically created I can't really use a specific ID and so I append numbers onto the end I have it so I can grab the dynamic id's and I can even get it so they all play the first vid on the page however, I can't seem to assign the play pause functionality to my buttons dynamically. here is the html I'm trying to adjust

```
                {% if post.clip %}
              <div class="container">
                <div class="overlay c-vid">
                    <video class="vid" playsinline="playsinline" width=100%>
                        <source src="{{ post.clip.url }}" poster="/media/sample.jpg" type='video/mp4'>
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                    <div class="vid-controls">
                         <div class="vid-bar">
                             <div class="vid-bar-fill">
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="vid-buttons">
                            <button id="play-pause{{ forloop.counter }}"></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
                {% endif %}
```

this is the css

```
.vid{
    width: 100%;
}
.c-vid{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.c-vid:hover .vid-controls {
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.vid-controls {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    width:100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-2px);
    transition: all 0.1s;

}

.vid-buttons button {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.vid-buttons button:before {
    content: '\f144';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 free';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.vid-buttons button.play:before {
    content: '\f144';
}

.vid-buttons button.pause:before {
    content: '\f28b';
}

.vid-bar {
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.vid-bar-fill {
    height: 10px;
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

and this is the javascript player I am trying to get to work

```
let video = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
let filling = document.querySelector('.vii-bar-fill');
let PABtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
let btn = [];


for (var i = 0; i < PABtn.length; i++) {
if (PABtn[i].getAttribute("id") !== null)
{
let xBtn = PABtn[i].getAttribute("id");
//console.log(i + xBtn);
let ibtn = document.getElementById(xBtn);
//console.log(btn);
btn.push(ibtn);
//console.log(btn)
}
}
//console.log(video)
//console.log(btn)

function togglePlayPause(a) {
//console.log("a="+a)
    if(video.paused){
       a.className = "pause";
       video.play();
    }
    else {
        a.className = "play";
        video.pause();
    }

}

for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
let xBtn = btn[i].id
let iBtn = document.getElementById(xBtn)
iBtn.addEventListener("click", function (iBtn) {
    togglePlayPause (iBtn);
});
}
for (i = 0; i < video.length; i++){
video[i].addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    var fillPos = video[i].currentTime / video[i].duration;
    filling.style.width = fillPos * 100 + "%";
});
}
```

any help or insight would be appreciated, just know these objects instantiate from django from a database in a for loop. I can get the videos and if I use the native player I can even play each individually but I want to program the player for better look and control than the default player.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way to do it but I'm not sure it's the simplest or most functional way. here is my end javascript

```
let video = document.querySelectorAll('.vid');
let filling = document.querySelector('.vid-bar-fill');
let btn = document.querySelectorAll("button[id]")

console.log(btn)
console.log(video)

function togglePlayPause(a) {
let xVid = a.srcElement.offsetParent.offsetParent.children[0]
    if(xVid.paused){
        a.srcElement.className = "pause";
        xVid.play();
    }
    else {
        a.srcElement.className = "play";
        xVid.pause();
    }

}
for (i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
let xBtn = btn[i]
//let xVid = video[i]
btn[i].addEventListener("click", function (xBtn) { //xVid wouldn't add here
    togglePlayPause (xBtn);
});
}
```

so basically I just fed the button identifier through to the function, from there I was able to drill up then drill down the attributes I needed until I finally found the video attribute for the button attribute and that allowed the individual movie to play for the individual button. For some reason using btn.indexOf never worked, trying to feed 2 arguments into the anonymous function never worked and I'm not sure exactly why. But this works and so I'm satisfied. If anyone has any other suggestions I'd be more than happy to try and clean up this code a bit more.